# Arrogant behavior by high reputation users

Tags: discussion

Is justifying that user's with high reputation can talk however they like?

And will a flag on them be easier to deny just because they simply can't be that wrong?

Bonus info:

A question is consisted of three parts and you decide that the third part should be moved to a new question because the first two parts are answered in a detailed way, but a user answered the third part, BUT you update and say that you moved the third part and you post the link, but that user goes to both questions and posts the same complaints... that his answer was good enough and *REFUSES* to copy the answer for moral reasons.... And states that MY behavior is bad.... Why? 2/3 were answered and deserved the green mark, 1/3 was anwsered but there was some debate and I moved it to a new one. Why should someone get bullied?

Comment: We have somewhat long tradition of very high rep users being suspended and what not... You are assuming things that are not consistent with that history.

Comment: Balanced reply: [Post only one question at once](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6580/43351). But: [Be nice](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). The second is more important.

Comment: Here are some pertinent links: [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/488049/8348), [moved third part](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/488416/8348).

Answer (score 6):

People will always have some bias to side with the person they know best.  As people with high rep are known better, they will always have something in their advantage that a low-rep user doesn't have.  That's just by nature of how humans work.

That said: Please realize that the flag-handlers do their best to try and address the actual problem, and to ignore who is talking against whom.  There is a history here on MSE of very high rep users being rebuked and even suspended (for very non-trivial durations) because of the content of their comments.

I'm very sorry that you had a bad experience with those questions and that user, and I hope this doesn't discourage you from participating on Math.SE.  I believe the user in question was somewhat upset that you did not notify him directly when you split the question (more on this in the section below).  But, we must all remember to be nice (especially to the more recent members of MSE). `:)`

**Regarding notifying people:**
If you need to notify someone (for example, if you wanted to let someone called "userX" know that you are splitting a question), there are two ways to do so:

1. **Use an "@" notification in a comment**.  If you write "@userX I'm splitting this question", then userX gets a pop-up that says you notified them.  However, if you just write "Hi, userX! I'm splitting the question," then they may never know that you were talking to them.
2. The one exception to this is if you are **commenting on one of their own questions/answers**.  That is, if userX made an answer, and I comment on that answer, they get a notification popup.

So, to be safe, if you are going to significantly change a question, notify the people (using a method from above) whose answer(s) may be affected.

Comment: Honestly, when it comes to flags for abusive behavior, I am, if anything, more likely to be biased against high reputation users, because they should know better by now.

Comment: If I update my question, will a message pop to the answerers? (This answer is great by the way... new users don't know the "policy" about high rep users)

Comment: @user2692669 Updating/editing the question does not make a message pop up for the people who have answered the question.  This is somewhat counter-intuitive, but it is the case...